# Write A program to accept Four digit number from user and count zero , odd and even digits from the entered number

Tags: python, count

Write A program to accept Four digit number from user and count zero , odd and even digits from the entered number. Pls check where I am making erorr??

```
count_of_zero = 0
count_of_odd = 0
count_of_even = 0

n = int(input("Enter 4 digit number: "))

    for count in str(n):
        if count == 0:
            count_of_zero += 1
        elif count % 2 == 0:
            count_of_even += 1
        elif count % 2 != 0:
            count_of_odd += 1
    print(f"The count of Zero in {n} is {count_of_zero}, The count of Even digits in {n} is {count_of_even} & the count of Odd digits in {n} is {count_of_odd}")
```

Comment: It's not indented properly. Is that the error you are asking about?

Comment: `count in str(n)` , you convert everything back to strings and then try to do modulo math on strings, you need to convert each `count` back to an integer

Comment: Additionally to the code not being indented probably, `count` is of type string. So you need to cast to int before doing arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the user's entered value as a string until you need to perform an arithmetic check on it. Below I only convert each digit in turn to an int

```
count_of_zero = 0
count_of_odd = 0
count_of_even = 0

n = input("Enter 4 digit number: ")

for count in str(n):
    count = int(count)
    if count == 0:
        count_of_zero += 1
    elif count % 2 == 0:
        count_of_even += 1
    elif count % 2 != 0:
        count_of_odd += 1
print(f"The count of Zero in {n} is {count_of_zero}")
print(f"The count of Even digits in {n} is {count_of_even}")
print(f"& the count of Odd digits in {n} is {count_of_odd}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count_zero = 0
count_odd = 0
count_even = 0
num = input("Enter a four digit number")
l=len(num)
if l != 4:
    print("This is not a 4 digit number")
else:
    for i in num:
        if int(i) == 0:
            count_zero= count_zero+1
        elif int(i)%2!=0:
            count_odd= count_odd+1
        elif int(i)%2==0:
            count_even=count_even+1
print('Number of zeroes', count_zero)
print('Number of odds', count_odd)
print('Number of even', count_even)
```